# Plugging in my dishwasher and water filter to the same outlet with an extender

Tags: receptacle, kitchens, dishwasher

I have two appliances that I need to plug in to the same outlet. These are:

A dishwasher - Bosch Benchmark 40-Decibel Top Control 24-in Built-In Dishwasher (Stainless Steel) ENERGY STAR

A water purifier - Waterdrop RO Reverse Osmosis Water Filtration System, TDS Reduction, 400 GPD Fast Flow, Tankless,

Can I plug them both in to the same outlet by using an extender? I am particularly worried about the dishwasher as it is high power and don't want to harm it by sharing power with a water purifier (which is low power)

Best,

RS

Comment: You could possibly get clearer answers or options if you indicated what receptacle configuration you already have.

Comment: What does that mean? Is it the configuration of the power outlet? That is two outlets - one is switched for the insinkerator. Other is free. It is in this free outlet that I want to run my dishwasher and the water purifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Don't use an extender!

Assuming an extender is some sort of little 3-to-1 (or similar) gadget to just "make extra outlets", those are not normally recommended for (a) permanent use, (b) hidden use or (c) high power use.

- Permanent Use - They get forgotten and they are an extra point of failure since they are just "hanging around" so they are not really *attached* in any permanent way.
- Hidden Use - Since they are not really attached in any permanent way (screwed in), they can come loose *without you knowing because they are hidden inside the sink cabinet*. Loose is worse than *out*. If an extender or anything else comes totally out, you research the problem and plug it back in. But if something is loose then it can lead to high-resistance connections, arcing and other problems which can lead to **fire**.
- High Power Use - The first two problems are multiplied when dealing with high power use (e.g., dishwasher when running the heating element), plus many extenders, extension cords, etc. are actually rated *in the fine print* for only low power usage. Not a problem (generally) for occasional use, but for frequent and hidden usage, this is a big problem.

The proper solution is to replace a single receptacle with the more typical duplex receptacle, or if this is already a duplex receptacle (e.g., split circuit - top = disposal, bottom = dishwasher) then add a new duplex receptacle next to it. If you do not need a new circuit (which depends on total power requirements - separate question!) then this should be a fairly straightforward upgrade, at least if you have easy access to the existing receptacle/box.

Comment: This is a bit scare-monger. OP hasn't stated what country/system. This is perfectly acceptable in the UK. For the US I wouldn't like to guess. Your electric is… weird :P

Comment: Ahh…. I looked at the OP's other question - mention of "2-prong" means it cannot be UK. Scare away ;))

Comment: @Tetsujin I wasn't sure at first but then I noticed "24-in" - which is a standard US dishwasher size - other places presumably use some "cm" thing... and ENERGY STAR is a US govt. rating system for energy usage. Therefore I assumed US and answered.

Comment: I hadn't really spotted those,. but EU is 300mm, close-ish to 24" & EnergyStar is I think completely international (though in the Uk you're more likely to see it on a computer monitor than a dishwasher - we have a whole bunch of confusing 'letter' ratings - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_energy_label

Comment: [EnergyStar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_Star) is a US thing. However, when it comes to computer monitors and a lot of other consumer electronics (as opposed to major appliances) you will see EnergyStar outside the US because these things now use 90V-250V power supplies so the only thing the manufacturer has to change for different locations is the (passive) power cord. Cheaper to keep everything the same - put the EnergyStar sticker on everything (costs little, sounds environmentally friendly), international multi-language documentation and...done.

Comment: Sounds like a whitewash;)) <j/k> Thanks for the extra info. One day I'll get a grasp of the US structure. I'm just used to "Plug it in. Done" So long as you don't try to run 2 2kW heaters off one extension you're likely to get away with it over here, everything consumer is 13A total load.

Comment: To be honest, if you simply use an extender as asked, **it will work**. The issue is that, particularly long-term, it isn't very safe because the extenders aren't designed (or certified) for that type of usage.

Comment: Everything here has to be certified 13A (though it *may* be fused for less) & earthed, including extension cords & multi-way sockets etc (the only proviso being if it's coiled or on a drum, like something for the garden, 100ft etc it must all be unwound for heat dissipation)

Comment: The issue here is two parts: # 1 - Extension cords, adapters, etc. are sometimes rated  for < 15A, *which is crazy, but they are allowed to do it*. But # 2 is that *even if rated for 15A, *it isn't a good idea to hide away a "temporary extension"*.

Comment: If your code isn't up to it, then the code ought to be changed. "crazy, but" is no excuse for poor code. Extensions *ought* to be safe for consumers to use in all "sensible" situations (because that's what consumers do; they don't measure & calibrate, they 'just plug things in'). If they're not, there is something terribly wrong with the code. Under-rating an extension with a smaller fuse in the UK is a safety measure for low-power uses, it's not because the extension cannot be rated for 13A. Such would be illegal.

Comment: I think a large part of it, for better or worse, is that while US States adopt (generally, with variants) NEC as "code", NEC (for the electrical code itself) and UL (for products that get installed and used by the NEC) are private organizations - essentially insurance based. So there is a bit more manufacturer/industry influence than there might be (then again, maybe not...lobbyists) if it were purely governmental regulation. End result though is that a lot of stuff is out there (not even counting uncertified junk) that people can easily misuse *and not even know they are doing something bad*.

Comment: I am in the US. I would love to hear that I can put them together in an extension cord. As putting a new power outlet over there will be very expensive. I can of course invest in a "safe" heavy duty extension cord and securely fasten it to the wall. Dishwasher only runs once a day and the water purifier probably runs more regularly.

Comment: I understand that it would be expensive to put a **new circuit**. Would it really be that expensive to replace the existing receptacle with a larger group - single with double (actually, that is trivial if it is a standard box) or double with quad (some drywall or cabinet work *or* a surface mount/extender on top of the existing box?

Comment: Agreed. That is what I will do. Thank you